# Keep required tag in inputs while using onclick()

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using inputs with required tag, and at this moment it's not working and the submit can be easily done even without a word inside the inputs.
I've searched abit for the reason and I guess that this is happening because I'm using the onclick function.

```
<form id="regform" method="POST">
First name: <input type="text" id="firstname" required  ><br>
Last name: <input type="text" id="lastname" required ><br>
Username: <input type="text" id="username" required><br>
Password: <input type="password" id="password" required><br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" required>Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" >Female
<input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="regBtn(event)">
</form>
```

Is there a way to keep the required active while using onclick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Right now you have such line somewhere:

```
document.getElementById("regform").submit();
```

Which ignore any built in validations and just submits the form.

Instead, move the function call to the form's onsubmit like this:

```
<form id="regform" method="POST" onsubmit="return regBtn(event);">
```

And change the function to return true or false instead of forcing submit:

```
function regBtn(event) {
    if (some_cond_here) {
        //all is good, let's submit the form!
        return true;
    } else {
        //something is off, cancel form submission:
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will preserve the built in HTML5 form validation.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/fLaZp/) - have username with one or two letters only to see the manual validation kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

Remember: The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.

More safer is to do like this:

```
<form id="regform" method="POST">
First name: <input type="text" id="firstname" class="required"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" id="lastname" class="required" ><br>
Username: <input type="text" id="username" class="required"><br>
Password: <input type="password" id="password" class="required"><br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" class="required">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" >Female
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Register" onclick="regBtn(event)">
</form>
```

And jQuery code:

```
 $(".required").each(function() 
    {
      if ($(this).val() == "") 
        {
            $('#submit').prop('disabled','disabled');   
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some lines in your regBtn function.

```
function regBtn(event) {
    if (!Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[required]:not([required=false])')).every(function (element) {
        return element.value != '';
    })) {
        return false;
    }
    //main function
}
```